# How doesnt my php code connect to the database..using Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

First forgive me if the code is not in an organized manner, I have tried to insert code in a neat manner but by the time I fix it, the system times out, so I cant post and have to do it all over again..so this time I am not going to adjust the code.. just copy past it into forum

I created a from called product_insert.html.. and a php script called product_insert.php. They are both located in a sub folder called Final exam, in the htdoc folder of xampp.

After entering data into form, the next screen basically shows me the script of the product_insert.php. I cannot figure out why it does not make the connection. Also the database is called final_exam.

i have edited my code to the following and i am still getting errors

```
<html>
  <head></head>
 <body>

<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Final exam") 
 or die(mysql_error());

//echo "We have successfully connect to our DB.<br/>";

  mysql_select_db( "final_exam") or die(mysql_error());

//echo "Successfully opened DB.<br/>";

//pull values from the URL and put them each in a variable

    $Description = addslashes($_GET["Description"]);
    $Quantity = addslashes($_GET["Quantity"]);
    $Price = addslashes($_GET["Price"]);
    $Vend_id = addslashes($_GET["Vend_id"]);

    if($Description && $Quantity && $Price && $Vend_id)
    {
            echo "test1";

    }
        else
    {
        echo "test2";
    }

    if(isset($Description) && !empty($Description) 
    && isset($Quantity) && !empty($Quantity)
    && isset($Price) && !empty($Price)
    && isset($Vend_id) && !empty($Vend_id))
    {           
      $SQLstring = "INSERT INTO student (id, first_name,last_name,address, e_mail,             
gpa)
VALUES (NULL, '$first', '$last', '$address', '$email', 0.0)";

$QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
 Or die("Insert Broke!!!");

echo "insert complete";
    }   
    else
    {
    echo "You are missing some values...Please press the back button and retry!";
    }
//redirect back to our list page since the insert worked
 header("location: db_connect.php");        
    ?>{/PHP]

<!--Insert Complete: click <a href="product_list.html">here</a> to go back to the     
list!-->
    </body>
</html>
```

i have edited my code to the following and i am still getting errors

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php

        $host = "localhost"; // change this as required
        $username = "root"; // change this as required
        $password = "password"; // change this as required
        $db = "final_exam"; // your DB  

            $DBConnect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") 
                or die("Could Not Connect");
            //echo "We have successfully connect to our DB.<br/>";

            mysql_select_db( "final_exam")
                or die(mysql_error());
            //echo "Successfully opened DB.<br/>";

            //pull values from the URL and put them each in a variable
            $Description = addslashes($_GET["Description"]);
            $Quantity = addslashes($_GET["Quantity"]);
            $Price = addslashes($_GET["Price"]);
            $Vend_id = addslashes($_GET["Vend_id"]);

            if($Description && $Quantity && $Price && $Vend_id)
            {
                echo "test1";

            }
            else
            {
                echo "test2";
            }

            if(isset($Description) && !empty($Description) 
                && isset($Quantity) && !empty($Quantity)
                && isset($Price) && !empty($Price)
                && isset($Vend_id) && !empty($Vend_id))
            {           
                $SQLstring = "INSERT INTO student (id,                          
VALUES ('$Description', '$Quantity', '$Price', '$Vend_id')";

                $QueryResult = @mysql_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
                    Or die("Insert Broke!!!");

                echo "insert complete";
        }   
            else
            {
                echo "You are missing some values...Please press the back 
button and retry!";
            }
            //redirect back to our list page since the insert worked
            header("location: product_list.php");       

        ?>

        <a a href="product_insert.html">Click here</a> to go back to the list!-->
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why is this in your code `[PHP]` and `/PHP]` ? If that IS your code, then delete those. Plus I noticed this commented out `product_list.html` your file wouldn't be `.html` instead of `.php` now would it?

Comment: I see no other reference to `$DBConnect`. Your DB credentials should look something like this `$DBConnect = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Could Not Connect To The Server");` if anything instead of `mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Final exam")` and use `$host = "localhost"; $username = "username"; $password = "password"; $db = "your_db";` --- This is a debugging issue.

Comment: here are my changes so far. Please review $DBConnect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") 
    or die(mysql_error());
   echo "We have successfully connect to our DB.<br/>";
  
   mysql_select_db( "final_exam")
    or die(mysql_error());
   echo "Successfully opened DB.<br/>";

Comment: What changes? I don't see an update.

Comment: after i make changes as suggested.. when i enter data into form i get the following result..instead of connet to database..i get..............."; $DBConnect=mysql_select_db( "final_exam") or die(mysql_error()); echo "Successfully opened DB.
"; ?> Click here to go back to the list!-->

Comment: You need to edit your question, not posting code as a comment. Plus what is this doing in your (posted) code `[PHP]` and `/PHP]` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you any further. I suggest you find tutorials and study them fully. I deleted my answer, because it apparently did not serve your purpose in regards to your DB structure, which I have no idea as to how it is setup. Remember that your `INSERT` and `VALUES` need to match/paired up. I spent enought time already and I wish you well, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

You are missing either user or password in your connection string.Instead you use the db name.
Also you are mixing  mysqli and mysql functions.

Comment: This is my user and password to the database..$DBConnect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")

Comment: @Darius That line belongs on top of your code. That's why you're not connecting. Plus I don't know what this is doing at the bottom of your code `header("location: db_connect.php");` if that's where your `$DBConnect` is, you're not doing it right.

Comment: I changed the header code at bottom to the following.. <a a href="product_insert.html">Click here</a> to go back to the list!-->....is this correct

Comment: @Fred as far as the line you said belong on top of the code.. i made changes i hope this is what you meant................................................................ <?php
    $DBConnect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") 
    or die(mysql_error());
    echo "We have successfully connect to our DB.<br/>";
  
    $DBConnect=mysql_select_db( "final_exam")
    or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Successfully opened DB.<br/>";
  
    //pull values from the URL and put them each in a variable
    $Description = addslashes($_GET["Description"]);
    $Quantity = addslashes($_GET["Quantity"]);

Comment: @Darius I will post reformatted code in an answer shortly and you could give that a try. There will be some added instructions/information regarding `header("location: db_connect.php");`

Comment: ok this really sucks the comment field does not allow enough text space.. so i cant show you changes to all my code and i am still getting major errors.. how is this helpful by limiting comment to such a minute space.... ugh i am so frustrated..

Comment: @fred Thank you so much, you dont know how many forums I have posted this too, and got absolutely no response or answers, and i also tried researching the issue myself on so many tutorial sites.. it gets confusing some say mysql_connect others say $dbconnet=mysqli... neither worked for me..

Comment: @Darius: Comments are for requesting clarification and/or to suggest improvements / additions, not for posting code. If you want to show us the updated code, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19744572/1438393) your question to do so!